# Add 1 to a value in a div onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a forum that people comment on other people's entry which i submit the data to the database via ajax. I have a div called `"total_number"` which have the total number of responses to a particular subject. I have a script that adds 1 to the number in the `total number` div on click on a submit button.

Now my problem is since the subject area is nested i'm finding it difficult to make the count to a particular row when its button is click. For example when i click on the submit button for row one, it adds up correctly, but when i click the next button being row two, the count doesn't work. So i need to find a script that can make up for the nested records so it counts to a particualr row when its button its click. I managed to add +1 to  the `total_number` div so when each div is repeated it adds +1 to it. That total_number1, total_number2, but still fails to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form1').on('submit',function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        // Disable submit button on this specific form
        $('.button-add', this).text('Submitted').prop('disabled', true);

        data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_comment.php",
        data: data

        }).success(function() {
              window.counter=parseInt($('#total_number').html());
            window.counter++;
            $('#total_number').html(window.counter);




        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a separate total for each row?  Or are you just adding up all comments from all rows and showing the total in one place?

Comment: there is a seperate row for each

Comment: Then you can't use `#total_number` - IDs must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If your comments have a class you can always just count how many of those objects are there.

For example:

```
var count = $(".comment-wrapper").length;
```

Now whether you need to add 1 to it or not, depends on whether you are doing it before or after new comment is added. Considering it is in succcess, I am assuming it is after, so you don't need to add 1 to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a counter on every row, and want each to sum independently (just the comments in its own row), then in your success function, find the `total_number` element (make it a class) immediately preceding the relevant submit button, get its html, parse and increase by one:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $check = $(this).prevAll('.total_number:first');
  var counter = parseInt($check.html());
  counter++;
  $check.html(counter);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="total_number">4</div>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
<div class="total_number">12</div>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: i just run your snippet is it works fine, when i embed into my script it fails to work. can you phrase it into my script?